# insert into not work in function postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, function, procedure, insert-update

I have the following procedure, when I run it displays all the insertions in console, the field ind_id is increased but does not save any record.

```
create or replace function renameDescripcionTramite() returns varchar as $$
declare 
    aguja record;
    pajar record;
    last_id integer;
begin
    for aguja in 
        select trim(t.tra_descripcion) tra_descripcion  from tab_tramite t 
        join tab_serietramite st on st.tra_id = t.tra_id 
        group by t.tra_descripcion
        order by t.tra_descripcion loop
            for pajar in
                select u.uni_id,s.ser_id,st.sts_id,t.tra_id,trim(t.tra_descripcion) tra_descripcion
                from tab_unidad u join tab_series s  on u.uni_id = s.uni_id
                join tab_serietramite st on st.ser_id = s.ser_id 
                join tab_tramite t on t.tra_id = st.tra_id
                order by u.uni_id,s.ser_id,t.tra_id loop
                if aguja.tra_descripcion = pajar.tra_descripcion then
                    insert into tab_indexpediente (uni_id,ser_id,tra_id) values (pajar.uni_id,pajar.ser_id,pajar.tra_id);-- returning ind_id into last_id;
                    --update tab_serietramite set wid = last_id where sts_id = pajar.sts_id;
                    RAISE NOTICE 'insert into tab_indexpediente (uni_id,ser_id,tra_id) values (%',cast(pajar.uni_id as text) 
                        || ',' || cast(pajar.ser_id as text) || ',' || cast(pajar.tra_id as text) || ')';
                end if;
            end loop;
        --RAISE NOTICE '  ANTERIOR ES %',aguja;
    end loop;
    return tra_descripcion;
end;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Can someone help me please?

Comment: Are you saying that the `INSERT` statement doesn't insert a record? Do you get the `INFO` message from `RAISE NOTICE`? Do you get an error (if yes, then the `INSERT` is probably rolled back)? What error do you get? Also, `RETURN tra_descripcion` should cause an error as there is no variable of that name defined.

Comment: tra_description does not cause any error, since it is only a text-type output, the display showing the NOTICE is: NOTICE:  insert into tab_indexpediente (uni_id,ser_id,tra_id) values (13,269,17), It seems that everything runs perfectly,

Comment: But `tra_descripcion` is not declared anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I did not know that this would affect the procedure.

Thank's laurenz Albe